# ¿Como cambio el color de el botón?

Tags: html, c#, css, asp.net

Contexto:

Tengo 2 botones de los cuales quiero cambiar su color cuando lo presione y cuando presione el segundo botón el primero vuelva a su color por defecto y viceversa.

CODIGO:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnConsulta1" runat="server" Text="Guias" 
 BackColor="#CCFF99" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="Blue" Height="25px" 
OnClick="Consulta1_Click"  Width="91px" O/></td>
```

Trate de ocupar CssClass pero no hace nada con el código que pongo en CSS

¿Que debería hacer?

Estoy ocupando Asp.net, HTML, C#

Comment: Intentaste con Javascript/JQuery? O por x o y motivo no puedes? Algo como: 
$('#btnConsulta1').css({"background-color": "#52BE80"}); //VERDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo. Te recomiendo hacerlo con JavaScript/Jquery.

usando c#, podrías cambiar el color de los botones de la siguiente manera:

```
 protected void btnConsulta1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      btnConsulta1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
      btnConsulta2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
 }

  protected void btnConsulta2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       btnConsulta1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
       btnConsulta2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
  }
```

Para hacerlo desde JavaScript, ejecuta la función desde el evento OneClientClick:

```
  <style>
    .mystyle {
      background-color: green;
      color: white;
    }
    </style>

    <script>
    function AddClass(BtnId) {
        var element = document.getElementById(BtnId);
      element.classList.add("mystyle");
    }
    
    </script>

<asp:Button ID="btnConsulta1" runat="server" Text="Guias 1" OnClientClick="AddClass(this.id)"
BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="Blue" Height="25px" 
OnClick="btnConsulta1_Click"  Width="91px"/>
```